# Attach child process to debugger automatically

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, debugging, process

If the main process is currently being debugged in Visual Studio, how can I have it so any new processes it spawns are also attached to the same instance of Visual Studio as the main process is?

Currently the new processes are created just with a CreateProcess call, however I can add extra code or use a different API altogether if needed, as well as making changes to the project or solution configurations (each process has its own project in a single solution).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attaching to a child process automatically in Visual Studio during Debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422768/attaching-to-a-child-process-automatically-in-visual-studio-during-debugging)

Answer (score 14):

I know I am few years late here but Visual Studio 2013 should support this after installing an extension:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a1141bff-463f-465f-9b6d-d29b7b503d7a

Comment: indeed: and it is documented here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/24/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool.aspx