# Why debugging ASP.net can potentially harm your computer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

When I try to attach the `w3wp.exe` process in order to debug asp.net process, a pop-up alerts me that this "can potentially harm your computer".

[image]

I just wonder why.

Comment: I attached an image to see the full message.

Comment: It doesn't harm your computer. This is windows generated message to make you inform about accessing an exe that is unknown to it.

Comment: Why is unknown to the Windows?

Comment: @a_maar - What do you mean exactly?  This message is displayed when you attempt to debug ANY file.

Comment: Doesn't matters which file is, just why alerts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, some older trojans/viruses used debug attachment as a mean to hook into other programs/services.

Nowadays you get a warning. Focus here is not on the words 'harm your computer'. It asks you to check if the process listed is what you'd expect. Imagine that popping asking to debug chrome.exe or skype.exe when you was just idling. That would make me freak out for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Are you by any chance NOT running visual studio as Administrator? Visual studio needs to be running as Administrator to attach to the ASP.NET worker process without popping up that warning.

EDIT: Looks like this issue is answered in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414769/turn-off-visual-studio-attach-security-warning-when-debugging-iis)

Comment: Yes, I'm adminmistrator it's showed in the image attached.

Comment: Yes, but are you explicitly running VS as administrator? Even if you are logged in as an administrator, VS doesn't run with elevated privileges by default

Comment: Yes, in VS title bar is showed `(Aministrator)`