# Visual Studio - Attach to process shortcut

Tags: visual-studio

When I want to debug I have to do Debug->Attach to Process -> Look for a process in the list -> Attach.

I was wondering if I can create some kind of a shortcut to do this for me?

Comment: If you've situation like me, when you need to repeat the attach-to-processes operation using the same set of processes, grab [resurrect extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/043c7c91-e127-4616-bce0-39b869cee4b3) and give it a try. It helped me so I've published it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to write a macro which finds the `DTE.LocalProcess` you wan to target and automatically attach.  For example

```
Public Sub AttachShortcut()
  For Each proc In DTE.Debugger.LocalProcesses 
    If proc.Name = "what you're looking for" Then
      proc.Attach()
      Exit Sub
    End IF
  Next
End Sub
```

Note: This Stack Overflow Question is related and has a sample you may find useful

- [Attaching to a child process automatically in Visual Studio during Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422768/attaching-to-a-child-process-automatically-in-visual-studio-during-debugging)

Comment: Macros are no longer available in Visual Studio 2012. For more details, see http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/10/VS-Macros/

Comment: You can reuse macros code in VS 2012/2013 with Visual Commander http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/

Comment: John Rea's answer below should be marked as the new answer, or at least have its information included in the answer for people using Visual Studio 2012 and up.

The add-ins ReAttach and AttachTo are good examples.

Comment: I've written a blog post about how to create a shortcut with the Visual Commander extension: http://blog.markvincze.com/attach-to-process-shortcut-in-visual-studio/

Comment: This should be downvoted now. Ctrl + Alt + P is the shortcut, as said in the answer from Rajesh.

Answer (score 86):

The shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in `Visual Studio 2005 and above`.

Comment: would note that this get's hijacked by default re-sharper settings!

Comment: @EruPenkman Not with the Visual Studio scheme (as of ReSharper 9 and Visual Studio 2013)

Comment: I've been using ALT+D, P. This is faster.

Answer (score 16):

[image: Attach to Process Button]

To enable the 'Attach to Process' toolbar button in ***Visual Studio 2013, 2015, 2017, 2019, and 2022***

1. Right-click on any toolbar and click 'customize...'
2. Click the 'commands' tab
3. Click the 'Toolbar' radio button
4. Select the toolbar where you want your button to appear from the dropdown
5. Click the 'Add Command...' button
6. Select 'Debug' from the categories list on the left
7. Select 'Attach to Process' from the commands list on the right, and click ok. The button will appear on your selected toolbar.
8. Optionally, use the 'Move Up' and 'Move Down' buttons on the right to move your new button to your desired location within the toolbar. I keep mine just after the Debug button.

Answer (score 14):

Writing a macro is one option, however it cannot deduct which process to attach to by itself.

Another nice solution is to map the "Attach to process" command to a shortcut key:

(**Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard**, type attach, like i did in this example, and select a shortcut key):

[image]

Comment: yes. this will open up attach to process window. the above macro goes further. it finds the process and attaches.

Comment: i was not sure which process it is that he's after. starting to like macros more and more recently :)

Comment: It should already have built in shortcut Ctrl+Alt+P. Might be different if you chose different kbd settings.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the Alt key shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>P</kbd> to launch the "Attach to Process" window via Debug menu.

Once there, you can use your keyboard to search the list of Available Processes (e.g. type "w3wp" if you want to attach to an IIS app pool)

Answer (score 13):

This answer should work for **Visual Studio 2010**.

> **I like having buttons to do this on my debug toolbar**

https://gist.github.com/1406827

The gist contains a method for attaching to IIS (w3wp.exe) or ASP (aspnet_wp.exe) and also nunit (nunit-agent.exe). Instructions are included on how to add the macros to your debug toolbar.

Comment: I can't believe this answer hasn't got more votes yet. The steps are super easy to follow and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Adrian, glad it worked for you! This saved me a ton of time when I was doing .net work.

Comment: There are no macros in VS2012 so your answer is pretty useless

Comment: DotNetWise: thanks, I've updated this answer to reflect that.

Comment: The link on github does not explain how to actually do the installation of the product. It's not user friendly.  I'm not sure what to do with that code.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey There's instructions on how to install the macro at the top of the file. I haven't used VS in years though, so maybe I'm missing a critical step? Best of luck with this.

Answer (score 13):

For Visual Studio 2017, 2019, there is a [ReAttach extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8cccc206-b9de-42ef-8f5a-160ad0f017ae) available. Very handy.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. I'm unsure what the answers that suggest keyboard shortcuts are doing as that's not what the question was asking. Cheers!

Comment: VS 2019 is also supported.

Comment: I don't see VS2019 support listed in the https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErlandR.ReAttach you sure?

Comment: @MohammedDawoodAnsari I can see "Works with Visual Studio 2017, 2019". However, I don't use it anymore in VS 2019. In VS 2019 there's a built-in option for that: Debug -> Reattach to Process. It becomes available after you already attached to any process within given VS session.

Comment: Yes, you are right. VS 2019 got built in reattach, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I use this built in "Shortcut"

<kbd>ALT+D</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

this opens the debug menu, selects attach to process, scrolls down to w3wp.exe and attaches.

It's long but should work in multiple visual studio versions with no setup required, with or without resharper and it works when running multiple IIS processes as you can choose which process to attach to.

Comment: If you (are able to) set up all websites to reuse the same apppool there will only be one w3p process

Comment: How do you build a shortcut?

Answer (score 7):

Addins are probably a better way to do this now. I use one called "Attach to anything". You can find them in Visual Studio 2012. Go to "Tools" -> "Extensions and updates", search for "attach", and install "attach to anything".

Also see:
[Automate "Attach to Process" in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130239/automate-attach-to-process-in-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: This should be marked as the new answer, since macros were removed in 2012.

The add-ins ReAttach and AttachTo are good examples.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to reattach the last attached process.

It works for me in Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to use [Debugger.Launch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) as suggested here
[in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951124/visual-studio-auto-attach-to-a-process-when-the-process-is-spawned), because it doesn't need for references to the DTE (that's IDE-specific and  must be explicitly referenced into the project to be used)

Answer (score 0):

## VS extensions

- [Debug Attach Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ViktarKarpach.DebugAttachManager)
- [ReAttach](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErlandR.ReAttach)
- [Resurrect](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JaroslawWaliszko.Resurrect)

More: [Search the VS Marketplace for "attach"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=attach&target=VS&sortBy=Relevance)

## Keyboard

- The attach to process shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in Visual Studio 2005 and above. You can then press the first letter of the process name you want, e.g. <kbd>w</kbd> for `w3wp.exe` and it'll jump to that, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to attach.
- You can use the Alt key shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>P</kbd> to launch the "Attach to Process" window via Debug menu.

## Code

- Add [`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) to your code

---

Current release is VS2015 at time of writing.

*Go ahead and edit/extend this answer :-)*