# Automate "Attach to Process" in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am developing a .NET DLL for software which is not part of my solution (don't have source).

I'd really like to somehow implement a key shortcut that automatically attaches the DLL to a specific executable (ideally waiting for the exe to start).

What is the best way to go about this?

If there's a way to leave VisualBasic out of the picture that would be an extra bonus.
(No offense to VB fans but I just don't like it)

Comment: A pity that no one has answered this question.  I have the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since macros don't exist in Visual Studio 2012, you will need to add an extension.

[AttachTo](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0265ab0-df51-4100-8e10-1f84403c4cd0) is very good and lightweight.  Search for it in *Extensions and Updates* (in Tools) in Visual Studio.

> Adds "Attach to IIS", "Attach to IIS Express" and "Attach to NUnit" commands to Tools menu.
>
> Now you can start debugging web site hosted in local IIS server or failing NUnit test quicker than before:)
>
> AttachTo extension provides options to hide commands not relevant to you. You can also assign shortcut using Tools -> Options -> Keyboard.

Comment: [ReAttach](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8cccc206-b9de-42ef-8f5a-160ad0f017ae) is another good extension.

Comment: I've been using "Debug Attach Manager" with good success: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/19951adf-722a-4d92-a73a-6d7a3d70cfc4

Comment: [Debug Attach Manager for VS2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6a667daf-be94-4be5-a92a-71732b8dd60a).

Comment: Thanks @Keith! Reattach is working great for me.