# Automatically "Attach to Running Process" in Visual Studio 2012/2013

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have to debug in Visual Studio 2013 a site hosted on local IIS.

For that purpose I sistematically use the "`Debug -> Attach to Process -> w3wp.exe`".

I saw some macros solutions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6696746/185593), that should work for the Visual Studio versions **prior** to VS 2012...

Is there a way to do something on that point in the recent versions of VS?

Answer (score 6):

Two plugins that do this:

### Debug Attach Manager

Find it here: [VS2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/19951adf-722a-4d92-a73a-6d7a3d70cfc4) and [VS2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6a667daf-be94-4be5-a92a-71732b8dd60a)

Indeed after initial selection of workers it's a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to re-attach the same.

The plugin handily shows the title of websites with the workers.

### VSCommands

Find it here: [VS2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a83505c6-77b3-44a6-b53b-73d77cba84c8) and [VS2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6d1c265-7007-405c-a68b-5606af238ece)

This is a larger plugin, which is quite popular, and has similar features but arguably more beautiful UI:

[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be nice if one could run this automatically after a build.

Answer (score -5):

In VS 2013, Go to Tools-> Attach to procress-> select iisexpress.exe