# VS Community 2015, attach to process command missing from debug and tools menus?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I just "upgraded" from VS Express 2013 to VS Community 2015 and I can't find the `Attach to process` command anywhere.

I can access it using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, but I can't find how to get to it other than that, and I'm curious where it might be or why it's missing since the [help documentation for VS 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3s68z0b3(v=vs.140).aspx) says it should be found within the `Debug` menu.

---

In VS 2013 I always accessed it from the `Debug` menu, but it was also available in the `Tools` menu.

---

Here are screenshots from the `Debug` and `Tools` menus in VSC 2015:

[image: Debug menu]
[image: Tools menu]

Comment: Had the same problem in the enterprise version...

Comment: You might also like http://stackoverflow.com/q/6696746/10245

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know why the "Attach to Process..." menu isn't showing up for you, but should be able to add it manually to the Debug menu using the "Customize..." option under the Tools menu.

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Customize Dialog]