# Attach process to debugger in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, process

I'm trying to create a shortcut/menu item for attaching a specific process to the debugger in Visual Studio 2013.

As I understood macros are no longer available from 2012 to do it.

I'm also not interested in doing it from the code using [Debugger.Launch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx)  method or through the registry like mentioned here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.100).aspx

I just want the user the have a menu item in VS that he can click on whenever he wants to attach the process to the debugger.

What options do I have?

I prefer to write something on my own, but if I must use a plugin, let it be.

Thanks

Comment: Im using [resurrect](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JaroslawWaliszko.Resurrect) and it it's great.

Comment: I'm looking for something that will configure the VS in the first time the user opens the project. i.e user won't have to search manually for the process to attach even at the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [reattach](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErlandR.ReAttach), that allow attaching again to last debugged applications.

Comment: I'm looking for something that will configure the VS in the first time the user opens the project. i.e user won't have to search manually for the process to attach even at the first time.

Answer (score 0):

If so, I think one better suggestion is that reuse your existing Visual Studio macros in your current VS.

You could install the Visual Commander in your latest VS version.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyVlasov.VisualCommander

Reference:

[Visual Studio - Attach to process shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696746/visual-studio-attach-to-process-shortcut)

Comment: @user3364652, Will you use the Visual Commander in your side?