# Visual Studio 2015 - attach to process using macro

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2015, macros

I need to attach to the unmanaged process (Windows service), using Visual Studio 2015 debugger and macro. When you debugging processes under SCM you have 10 seconds to attach somewhere in startup point.

Since Visual Studio 2013 Macro recorder and editor is an extension available from [plugins Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio). Usage of old good VB macros like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696746/visual-studio-attach-to-process-shortcut) is unavailable, extension provides JS macros only.

So I'm trying to write this simple macro based on the example provided by the link

```
for (var process in dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses){
    if(process.Name == "my_service.exe"){
        process.Attach();
    }
}
```

It does not work. Did anyone had success with the same problem?

Comment: As you said that you attach to unmanaged process, whether it has the same issue using general process/app like one .exe or others? This document also shared detailed suggestions using the same way but much more detailed steps: https://blog.markvincze.com/attach-to-process-shortcut-in-visual-studio/, if possible, you could view it.

Comment: I've read it, Visual Commander seems to be not a completely free software

Comment: Do you download it here?https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyVlasov.VisualCommander#overview